# SQL query from forms application returning different result from when executed in SQL Management

Tags: c#, sql

I have a little bit of a strange scenario here. In my windows form application, I am checking whether a login exists in the database, and creating if not.  The issue I have is that on second run of the program, the created login is not being detected.

The code I have is:

```
const string checkLoginQuery = @"SELECT name  
                            FROM master.sys.server_principals
                            WHERE name = '@Name'";
    object loginExists;
    using (SqlCommand checkLoginCommand = new SqlCommand(checkLoginQuery, _connection))
    {
        checkLoginCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", _user));

        loginExists = checkLoginCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    if (loginExists != null)
    {
        m_logger.Info("Login already exists");
    }
    else
    {
        m_logger.Info("Creating login");
        string createLoginQuery = string.Format("CREATE LOGIN [{0}] WITH PASSWORD = '{1}'", _user,
                _password);
        using (SqlCommand createLoginCommand = new SqlCommand(createLoginQuery, _connection))
        {
            createLoginCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

The creation is working perfectly fine, but the first SqlCommand is always returning null.

When I run the query `SELECT name FROM master.sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'myName'` in SQL management, this is correctly returning the name of the login that was previously created.

From SQL Profiler, I am seeing my forms application generating the following query:

```
  exec sp_executesql N'SELECT name  
                            FROM master.sys.server_principals
                            WHERE name = ''@Name''',N'@Name nvarchar(6)',@Name=N'myName'
```

which returns null.

What is the difference in these queries, and how can I get around this issue?

Comment: `const string checkLoginQuery = @"SELECT name  
                            FROM master.sys.server_principals
                            WHERE name = @Name"` No need to `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you correctly using parameters you don't need quotes around @Name:

```
@"SELECT name  FROM master.sys.server_principals WHERE name = @Name";
```

Also as already mentioned use:

```
checkLoginCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", _user));
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use `@Name`.

```
checkLoginCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", _user));
```